# Python: need to stop running code, if a condition is met/not met

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a python code to check the validity of a string as per a specific MOD11 algorithm, but wanted to further check with regex if the string is in the correct structure to begin with.

```
TIN = '5562000'

import re
x = re.search("\d{7}(\d|K){1}", TIN)
if x != 'None':
    print ('Structure Valid')
    
    check = (int(TIN[0])*8) + (int(TIN[1])*7) + (int(TIN[2])*6) + (int(TIN[3])*5) + (int(TIN[4])*4) + (int(TIN[5])*3) + (int(TIN[6])*2)

    y = check / 11

    z = "{:.0f}".format(y)

    print(z, TIN[7])

    print((TIN[7]) is str(z))

    if ((TIN[7]) == str(z)) & (str(z) != '0'):
        print('Valid TIN')
    elif ((TIN[7]) == 'K') & (str(z) == '10'):
        print('Valid TIN')
    elif (TIN[7] == '0') & (str(z) == '11'):
        print('Valid TIN')
    else:
        print('Invalid TIN!')   

else:
    print('Invalid Structure')
```

When the structure is valid, i.e. number of characters is correct, all works fine. However, if there's a character missing in the TIN variable, I get this error:

```
    print(z, TIN[7])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

So, I need a way to NOT run this portion of the code, if TIN is not in the correct structure:

```
y = check / 11

z = "{:.0f}".format(y)

print(z, TIN[7])

print((TIN[7]) is str(z))

if ((TIN[7]) == str(z)) & (str(z) != '0'):
    print('Valid TIN')
elif ((TIN[7]) == 'K') & (str(z) == '10'):
    print('Valid TIN')
elif (TIN[7] == '0') & (str(z) == '11'):
    print('Valid TIN')
else:
    print('Invalid TIN!')
```

I tried while and for loops with the break function and sys.exit, also tried indentation, but I'm not that good yet to make it work. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: `if len(TIN) < 7: print("TIN less than 7 characters")` ?

Comment: As an aside `{1}` is never necessary or useful. If there is only one of something, just don't specify any repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key mistake is your comparison of the regex result:

```py
if x != 'None':
```

compares `x` with the string `"None"`, which is different from the `None` keyword:

```py
>>> None == "None"
False
```

You want your check to be:

```py
if x is not None:
```

then, everything should work.

Edit: Keep in mind that `re.search` allows for additional characters before and after the regex match. I think you might not want this here, so you might want to use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
try:
    print(z, TIN[7])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    #further code
```

It will try to perform the block inside `try`.
If it executes with no errors then it will continue further without considering `except` part.
If there is any problem in that block, it will execute the block inside `except` and store the error in `e`.

Comment: While I agree that in general, try-catch-handle is a pythonic approach, I don't think it's a good idea here. You're catching all Exceptions and the try-block would be relatively large. This would likely prevent us from noticing bugs, since the code can't fail anymore, it just simply returns "invalid" for any input.
It would be more appropriate to only catch IndexErrors. However, since the try block is pretty big, I think a length check at the beginning would be better. Notice that the regex search already did a length check, but the result was not checked correctly.